# Sorting entries containing different datatypes which are Concatenated

Tags: java, collections

How to sort a list in Java containing Concatenated String and integers( eg. RajPalav2014)Consider there are 1000's of entries?

Comment: 1. How do you want to sort? 2. What have you tried?

Comment: Damn, what if there are 1000000's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how it's different from sorting any other type of list. Try this:

```
    List<String> mixedStuff = new ArrayList<String>();
    mixedStuff.add("hello123");

    int sevens = 777;
    mixedStuff.add("alpha" + sevens);

    Integer eights = 888;
    mixedStuff.add("bravo" + eights.toString());

    Collections.sort(mixedStuff);
```